# Bulk Update not working in Entity Framework using EntityFramework.Utilities Nuget Package

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, nuget

I am using [EntityFramework.Utilities](https://github.com/MikaelEliasson/EntityFramework.Utilities) NuGet Package to Perform Bulk Insert and Bulk Update. Bulk Insert is working fine for me. But when I am trying to bulk update, I getting following error:

"An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'."

Following is my code

```
public virtual void BulkInsert(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            if (entities == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entities));

            EFBatchOperation.For(_Context, _Entities).InsertAll(entities);
        }

        public virtual void BulkUpdate(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
        {
            if (entities == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entities));

            EFBatchOperation.For(_Context, _Entities).UpdateAll(entities,x => x.ColumnsToUpdate());
        }
```

I building a list and sending it for bulk insert

```
List<SellerGroupAssignment> sellerGroupAssignmentList = new List<SellerGroupAssignment>();
                    //check all deassignList
                    foreach (
                        var modifiedGroup in
                            sellerList.Where(
                                current =>
                                    currentSellerGroups.Any(
                                        change => change.SellerId == current.SellerId && !change.IsDeleted)).ToList())
                    {
                        var updateGroup = Mapper.Map<SellerGroupAssignment>(modifiedGroup);
                        updateGroup.Created =
                            currentSellerGroups.Where(seller => seller.SellerId == updateGroup.SellerId)
                                .Select(x => x.Created)
                                .SingleOrDefault();
                        updateGroup.CreatedByUserId =
                            currentSellerGroups.Where(seller => seller.SellerId == updateGroup.SellerId)
                                .Select(x => x.CreatedByUserId)
                                .SingleOrDefault();
                        updateGroup.IsDeleted = true;
                        updateGroup.SellerGroupId = updateGroup.SellerGroupId;
                        updateGroup.SellerId = updateGroup.SellerId;
                        updateGroup.Modify();
                        sellerGroupAssignmentList.Add(updateGroup);

                    }
                    sellerGroupAssignmentRepository.BulkUpdate(sellerGroupAssignmentList);
```

In the Nuget documnetation it is said that, UpdateAll is generic method. We can specify the columns to update if required.

I got stuck with it. Can you please help me.

**EDIT**

Adding Queries from SQL Profiler

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[temp_SellerGroupAssignment_636204526825441555]([SellerId] int, [SellerGroupId] int, PRIMARY KEY ([SellerId], [SellerGroupId]))
go
select @@trancount; SET FMTONLY ON select * from [dbo].[temp_SellerGroupAssignment_636204526825441555] SET FMTONLY OFF exec ..sp_tablecollations_100 N'[dbo].[temp_SellerGroupAssignment_636204526825441555]'
go
insert bulk [dbo].[temp_SellerGroupAssignment_636204526825441555] ([SellerId] Int, [SellerGroupId] Int)
go
UPDATE [SellerGroupAssignment]
                SET

                FROM
                    [SellerGroupAssignment] ORIG
                INNER JOIN
                     [temp_SellerGroupAssignment_636204526825441555] TEMP
                ON 
                    ORIG.[SellerId] = TEMP.[SellerId] and ORIG.[SellerGroupId] = TEMP.[SellerGroupId]
go
```

Comment: Can you run tracing or a profiler on the database and provide us with the SQL that is being attempted to be run?

Comment: Added queries in Question

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the columns you want updated in the call to `ColumnsToUpdate()`:

```
EFBatchOperation.For(_Context, _Entities).UpdateAll(entities,x => x.ColumnsToUpdate());
```

Currently this is empty, thus no column is specified in the SET part of the SQL query:

```
SET

FROM
    [SellerGroupAssignment] ORIG
```

You can change this to:

```
EFBatchOperation.For(_Context, _Entities).UpdateAll(entities,x => x.ColumnsToUpdate(c => c.Created, c => c.CreatedByUserId, c => c.IsDeleted, c => c.SellerGroupId, c => c.SellerId));
```